# leading / lagging observations together with nested data

Tags: r

I want to generate a new variable based on

1.**a nested vector of the current observation**

2.**values from current and other observations.**

Here's my example:

```
D <- tibble(team = c(101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102),
            id = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
            x = c(3, 7, 5, 1, 4, 10),
            y = list(c(5,5,5), c(8,5,2), c(6,2,7), c(3,9,3), c(8,3,4), c(4,4,7)))
```

I want to create a new variable which equals

`abs(y[1] - x[id==1]) + abs(y[2] - x[id==2]) + abs(y[3] - x[id==3])`

This code is obviously wrong syntax, just for demonstration what I want to compute. Need to use current as well as leading or lagging (or both) observations of `x`, depending on value of `id`.

The expected result in this example would be `z = c(4, 10, 10, 14, 14, 6)`

I have tried something along the lines of `group_by(team)` followed by an attempt to use `map()` but I can't find anything promising.
What is the most elegant solution? I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Not clear how you get the `2, 5, 5, , 7, 7, 3`.  Each element in 'y' is a `vector`

Comment: I don't understand the expected output. For the first row it should be `abs(5 - 3) + abs(5 - 7) + abs(5-5) = 4 ` from what you describe

Comment: As @Cett mentioned, the values I got a different `D %>% group_by(team) %>% mutate(z = map_dbl(y, ~ sum(abs(.x -x))))`

Comment: Sorry! According to my example every value in ```z``` has to be multiplied by 2. So the correct solution is ```z = c(4, 10, 10, 14, 14, 6)```. 
(I had ```max(diff, 0)``` in mind, that explains the mistake.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map` to loop through the `list` column after grouping by 'team' and then get the `sum` of `abs`olute difference between that column and the 'x'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
D %>%
   group_by(team) %>%
    mutate(z = map_dbl(y, ~ sum(abs(.x -x)))) 
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   team [2]
#   team    id     x y             z
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>    <dbl>
#1   101     1     3 <dbl [3]>     4
#2   101     2     7 <dbl [3]>    10
#3   101     3     5 <dbl [3]>    10
#4   102     1     1 <dbl [3]>    14
#5   102     2     4 <dbl [3]>    14
#6   102     3    10 <dbl [3]>     6
```